# How to reroute all urls in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework

I got url aliases table in db and every time i want to reroute url to module, controller, action and arguments from db.

I'm doing this:

```
$frontController  = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':city/:name',
    array($arr_params->controller, $arr_params->action, $arr_params->module), array($arr_args));
$frontController->getRouter()->addRoute('h', $route);
```

But it doesn't work. How to make it work for all urls?

Comment: What doesn't work (and what does it do instead)? Where do you add the routes, how to you get the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a custom route class.  See a similar response here:

[how to get dynamic URL like mydomain.com/username using zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673923/how-to-get-dynamic-url-like-mydomain-com-username-using-zend-framework/3846911#3846911)