# Zend Framework - Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex - Concatinate Regex matches

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-rewriting, routes

I would like to be able to match a URL like this

www.site.com/cc/[action-name-first-part].12345.[action-name-second-part]

Basically the resulting action would be a concatenation of the 2 action name.

My current route looks like this

$ccRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
'cc/([^.]*).([^.]*).([^.]*)',
array('controller' => 'cc'),
array('action-first-part' => 1, 'arbitrary-number' => 2, 'action-second-part' => 3)
);

this partner matches fine. but with the third argument (mapping argument), how can I concat the 1 and 3 index and just pass the correct action to the controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, you cannot do this with the regex routes.  However, it's quite trivial to make a new route class that can do this.

Here is a quick answer on how to make your own route class.

[how to get dynamic URL like mydomain.com/username using zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673923/how-to-get-dynamic-url-like-mydomain-com-username-using-zend-framework/3846911#3846911)